# In .NET, failure to retrieve HTTP resource from W3C web site

Tags: c#, .net, http

Retrieving the resource at http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/XMLSchema.xsd takes around 10 seconds using the following mechanisms:

- web browser
- curl
- Java `URL.openConnection()`

It's possible that the W3C site is applying some "throttling" - deliberately slowing the response to discourage bulk requests.

Trying to retrieve the same resource from a C# application on .NET, I get a timeout after about 60-70 seconds. I've tried a couple of different approaches, both with the same result:

- `System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity()`
- `new WebClient().OpenRead(uri)`

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Would another API, or some configuration options, solve the problem?

Comment: I suggest your point your c# program at a known-good URL (e.g. www.google.com) to see if you can get a response back. That will help you determine if your code is wrong or if there is a networking type of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is they are (probably) checking for a `User-Agent` string. If it's not present, they send you to purgatory. .NET's http clients do not set this by default.

So, give this a shot:

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task TestMe()
{
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/XMLSchema.xsd"))
    {
        req.Headers.Add("user-agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)");
        using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var data = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

No idea why they do this; Maybe it's a bug in their back-end? (I sure wouldn't want to leave a socket open longer than it needs to be for no *good* reason). The request still takes 10-15 seconds, but it's better than the 120+ second timeout.